# Is there online php compiler that I can test with multiple php files?

Tags: php, jquery, compiler-construction

I am using [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/) and [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) for sharing my php code with others and using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) to share my jquery code with others.

Now I want to share a php script with others in which a form submission work is done. In my local machine I have two files. **1.** myform.php(contain form) **2.** _myform.php(action on form submission). How can I share this type of code online in running position.

So is there any online php compiler in which I can use multiple php files and jquery will be a plus.

Thanks

Comment: BTW there is one more I love to use: http://codepad.viper-7.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sign up for a free PHP hosting on http://www.byethost.com/ or http://www.freehostia.com/ or any similar site.
2. Upload your code there. It will run like a website.
3. For sharing, upload the code with .txt extension appended like `myfile.php.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there are some functions disabled for security reasons, but Yes:

- http://codepad.org/
- http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Those websites don't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try http://phpcompileronline.co.cc/

Answer (score 1):

you can check this : http://online-compiler.com, it is contain a good PHP editor and give you a personal workspace in a virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

This is very useful u can use the following url

http://phpresult.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried a tool to run my PHP files and I was happy with the tool. Check out http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php . Hope you guys find this tool useful like i did.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a live online web-enviroment (as in: a live website which accepts code from an unknown source and execute it), the awnser is short: no.

The security risks are just too great.

Comment: -1: There are loads of them. The security risks are quite easy to manage with a simple _chroot_ environment and some syscalls disabled. Isolation principles from basic security best-practices.